# Configure Apache so it doesn't display a site for IP based vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a CentOS LAMP server. It has several vhosts configured. If I navigate to:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/  (server IP)
```

Apache displays one of the sites. How can I configure Apache to show nothing or perhaps a 403 Forbidden? If it could show a forbidden before checking for malformed requests that would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first vhost that Apache picks up from your configuration is the default one picked when the name that the client sends doesn't match any configured vhost, so you'll have to make a vhost that sends 403 errors and ensure that it's picked up first in the httpd config.

Comment: Will this show the 403 even if it's a malformed request where a 400 would normally be served? Also what's the syntax in the vhost directive to issue the 403?

Comment: `Order Allow,Deny`, `Deny from all`.  Put it in a `<Location />` block in the default (first) vhost.

Comment: Thanks, the 403 can also be done by removing the `DocumentRoot` in the first vhost.